# Need Help to create Friendly URLs .htaccess URL Rewritng

Tags: php, .htaccess

i am looking for a htaccess code which helps me to  REWRITE my URLs as friendly URLs

i searched a lot in internet.. but didn't fine one

```
example.com/hospitals.php?cname=AOL Hospital    
should rewrite as example.com/hospitals/AOL Hospital   


example.com/collages.php?cname=Big O 
should rewrite as example.com/collages/Big O Collage
```

Comment: You searched a lot? google mod rewrite generator, first hit: http://www.generateit.net/mod-rewrite/

Comment: Have you tried anything? This can be done with the query_string: http://www.simonecarletti.com/blog/2009/01/apache-rewriterule-and-query-string/

Comment: @JimL it did't help me... :( please read my question ones again

Comment: @LarsEbert it didn't help me :(

Comment: So how did this not help you? Why exactly is your current solution not working? You need to tell us what exactly the problem seems to be.

Comment: @LarsEbert i am not good in English so i can't explain my problem clearly :( #sorry  if possible please read my question and try to answer below with the htaccess code

Comment: Stackoverflow is not a free coding service. I'd suggest you register for one of those sites if you wish to have code made for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You search like this?

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)$ $1.php?cmname=$2 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Thanks for your time. tried this

`http://example.com/Hospitals/BOPHospital`

i want this URL to `http://example.com/Hospitals.php?cname=BOP Hospital`


but it is showing >> Not Found

The requested URL /Hospitals/BOP Hospital was not found on this server.

Comment: @user2486438 What is exactly your syntax? First 3 char?

Comment: no. i just forgot to give space in my comment. you did correctly but it is showing `Not Found  The requested URL /Hospitals/BOP Hospital was not found on this server.

Comment: @user2486438 Your site on root or sub domain? And your file name `Hospitals.php` exactly with uppercase first char?

Comment: yes. it is uppercase first char. and my site is a root domain.. but still 404 error. if possible team viwver plesae..i will give my ID and pass

Comment: yes :( not working.. tried new code... http://kavalipages.com

this is actual website. search for Hospitals.. and click on a hospital name...

Comment: i have used this in my htaccess file `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ $1.php?cmname=$2
</IfModule>`

PS: actually it is cmname. its my spell mistake in my question

Comment: @user2486438 cmname contains space char. Please remove space char one hospital to try. For ex: `Latha Hospital` name change to `Latha`. Regex `([a-zA-Z0-9]+)` deny space char.

Comment: this this ... `kavalipages.com/Hospitals/Kandukuri Hospital`

it is not working but `http://kavalipages.com/Hospitals.php?cmname=Kandukuri%20Hospital` it is working

Comment: mod_rewrite is enable on your server?

Comment: Opps. sorry. i will contact bluehost team... 2min please!